# sphinx search query first 20 order by title WEIGHT and next 20 by title ASC no duplicate output

Tags: mysql, sql, sphinx

How to select via sql command on sphinx first first 20 rows order by title WEIGHT and next 20 order by title ASC ( total 40 results ) on the same sql command but to don't give duplicate title output.

I try this sql command but all title results is order via WEIGHT()

```
$sql = "SELECT *,MAX(WEIGHT()) AS tpw FROM vids_tab 
 WHERE MATCH('@title " . mysql_real_escape_string( 'fun | funny | today funny' ) . "') 
 GROUP 5 BY title ORDER BY tpw DESC, title ASC LIMIT 40 OPTION max_matches=40";
```

Answer (score 0):

Got to be honest, don't really see this being practical in a single query. Just issue two queries. And then remove any duplicates in the application.

In the second make sure over double the number of results, so even if need to remove 20 as duplicates, will still have 20.

If really do want one command, think going to need a UDF. On particular problem, is will need to know range of weights for the first 20 results (so can create a virtual column to sort by (ie to know if  row is in the first 20 results)

```
... ORDER BY IF(WEIGHT() BETWEEN topweight AND bottomweight, WEIGHT(), 0 ) DESC , title ASC
```

(that ISN'T a valid sphinxQL command, just demonstrating what would need to emulate) So first 20 would order by weight, non first would get same value, and so then order by title.